# Correcting aspect ratio of circle plot with matplotlib.patches

Tags: python, matplotlib, patch

I am using matplotlib.patches to generate a circle. However, the circle generated is not visually circular. It appears like an ellipse. It is probably due to some aspect ratio setting which I am not able to figure out with patches. How can I get a visually circular circle with matplotlib.patches module?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
grid = np.mgrid[0.2:0.8:3j, 0.2:0.8:3j].reshape(2,-1).T

patches = []

circle1 = mpatches.Circle(grid[4], 0.25, linestyle='-.', fill=False)

ax.add_patch(circle1)

ax.grid(color='r', linestyle='-.', linewidth=1)

# plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, bottom=0.1, right=0.5, top=0.5,
#                 wspace=0.1, hspace=0.1)
# plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the unequal height and width in the default `figsize`. Use a square figure size with equal width und height as

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))
```

with the correct desired output as below.

**Alternatively** you can also use the following line of code (put anywhere after defining the `ax` and before showing) to make an equal aspect ratio as

```
ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: It does produce a square figure but the aspect ratio changes as the figure resizes. Is there a permanent solution to this?

Comment: But once you put `ax.set_aspect('equal')`, the size doesn't matter right? Or am I unable to understand what you are trying to say? Explain please

Comment: Bazingaa @Bazingaa

Answer (score 3):

If you want a circle in data coordinates to appear circular in screen coordinates, you would need to set the aspect ratio of the axes to be equal.

You may choose

```
ax.set_aspect("equal")
```

to let the axes scale.

[image]

Or you may choose

```
ax.set_aspect("equal", adjustable="datalim")
```

to let the data scale

[image]

If, instead, you want to create a circle in screen coordinates directly, you can use a scatter plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.scatter([.5], [.5], s=10000, edgecolor="k", facecolor="none")
ax.grid(color='r', linestyle='-.', linewidth=1)
ax.axis([0,1,0,1])

plt.show()
```

[image]